# Python print a float with a given number of digits

Tags: python-3.x, printing, floating-point, formatting

I have some floating point values in Python. I would like to print them so that the have the same number of digits (sum of the integer and decimal parts)

For example considering the two numbers:

```
a = 12.123456
b = 123.1234567
```

I would like to print their value formatted as follows:

```
12.1234
123.123
```

So that they have the same length.

One simple way is the following:

```
if (val>100):
    print("%0.3f" % val)
else:
    print("%0.4f" % val)
```

Is there a smarter way to control both the number of integer and decimal digits at the same time in python so that the resulting string is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I thought about this solution that is basically a work-around for positive numbers:

```
LIM = 7;
a = 12.123456
b = 123.1234567
print(str(a)[:LIM])
print(str(b)[:LIM])
```

Comment: I suppose here you would run into trouble for negative numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The formating method for both integer and decimal is

```
>>> '{:06.2f}'.format(3.141592653589793)
'003.14'
```

the part before the `.` (`6` here) denotes the total length of padding (including the `.`), and after the `.` (`2f`here) denotes digits after decimal point.
Hope it helps. checkout the [link](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding).

Answer (score 4):

You can try to do something like this

```
print('{:.6}'.format(val))
```

Comment: Actually it works in most of the cases but not if the integer part is 0: for example it does not work in the case of 0.678923156 because it prints 6 decimals without counting the 0 integer part

Comment: it looks a bit scary, but will work for the case with zero at the beginning

`print(('{:.6}' if int(val) else '{:.5}').format(val))`

{:.5} - this will applied if integer part equals zero, in other cases {:.6}